# Fingerprint authentication on Android / avoid Samsung overlay?

Tags: android, authentication, samsung-mobile, fingerprint

I am attempting to implement fingerprint authentication in my application in a fashion similar to the 1Password and Bank of America apps:

[image]

[image]

I have been using the other questions on here as resources as well as this github project: https://github.com/Zlate87/android-fingerprint-example

However, the end product has yielded a strange overlay that is presumably the work of Samsung (testing on an S7 Edge):

[image]

My other concern is that all the solutions I have seen are rather convoluted, especially when compared to how simple it is to implement Touch ID in iOS (5 to 10 lines of code at most).

Can anyone please explain what this Samsung overlay is and perhaps let me know if implementing this functionality is really so complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Found a much better sample project that doesn't display that strange Samsung popup: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/issues

And yes, fingerprint auth on android really is a PITA.